# Adapter sockets for different TO can pin circle diameters

Tags: transistors, connector, adapter, socket, laser-diode

I need to mount a laser diode from Ushio with **2.0 mm** pin circle diameter,

[image: Ushio laser diode]

onto a combined [strain relief/ESD protection cable](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=SR9A) from Thorlabs, which has a [socket](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=S8060) with **2.54 mm** pin circle diameter,

[image: Thorlabs socket]

Are there any adapter sockets to make the connection possible? I have spent an hour searching online, but could not find any solution whatsoever.

(Image sources: Ushio, Thorlabs)

Comment: Why do you want to put the laser diode in a socket? Did you consider that it may need to be soldered directly into a PCB for thermal reasons?

Comment: Your links are broken: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: @DavideAndrea Thanks, fixed the links! :)  The laser diode has several hundred milliwatts output power, so I actually need to mount it in a machined copper fixture with attached heat sink in order to provide cooling. The fixture will clamp down onto the header (rim) of the TO can, since solder contacts to the pins/leads alone will probably provide insufficient thermal contact.

Comment: The socket adapter is mainly to provide proper electrical contact without having to solder the pins, as I need to keep the strain relief/ESD protection cable removable, so I can change between different laser diodes

Comment: Just bend the pins a bit?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a 2-row unshrouded female header turned 45 degrees?

You would need one with a 1.42 mm pitch and row spacing. The closest I can find is 1.27 mm. https://www.digikey.com/short/wbqmhzzn

Comment: +1, like the idea! :) Might give it a shot in the next build... I ended up stacking an additional socket with 2.0 mm pin circle between the diode and the socket, then shoving it into the socket as far as its pins would allow and filling the gap with epoxy. The additional socket acts as a make-shift adapter, so **its** pins get bend instead of the diode's (so the latter can be easily removed and reinserted).

Comment: ...still, I believe some manufacturer should consider producing appropriate adapter sockets - I can't believe I'm the only person ever confronted with this issue. We have adapters literally for everything, why not for diodes? If anyone happens to know a manufacturer, please share